# Do Briskers use a particular siddur?

Tags: prayer-book, nusach-ashkenaz, communities, brisk

Presumably Briskers generally daven nusach Ashkenaz.  Is there a particular siddur associated with Brisk, perhaps with haskomos from Brisker roshei yeshivos?

Comment: Maybe nusach HaGra

Comment: There are siddurim with haskamot? I'm not sure that I've ever seen such a thing.

Comment: I think in general, the whole idea of special siddurim, with odd features that distinguish them from others, the use of which identifies you as part of a certain group--is a chasidic thing. People in 'the yeshiva world' are usually not into that sort of thing.

Comment: @paquda that sounds right, but what about the [variations in Ashkenaz siddurim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16455/1304), then?  Just not a big deal?

Comment: @ShimonbM definitely certain siddurim come with haskamos.  Tefila Yeshara comes immediately to mind, although of course those are more on the Keser Nehora commentary... Chemdas Yisroel has them too.  As Ashkenaz siddurim go, Siach Tefila has one from R' Chaim Kanievsky shlita.

Comment: @yoel, yes--my impression is it's not a big deal. The variations don't have halakhic significance, i.e., you fulfill your obligation either way. So for people whose framework is halakhah and gemara, these things aren't important. For hasidim, who are interested in preserving minhagim of their rebbes and in trying to be 'correct' kabbalistically, differences in wording can seem important.

Comment: @paquda interestingly, the Besht says that the exact wording of davening doesn't really matter and that a person should make a big thing about it.

Comment: Look at this video of Rav Dovid Soloveitchik shlita, you can see the classic kol peh siddur in the background : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxgUCmFRvW4
Also I think Briskers dont respect kol peh nusach word by word, it let me think that there is no "brisker siddur". As many people they may use a siddur but have their own specifics here and there while davening

Comment: Correction : it was not siddur kol peh on the video but siddur kehilos yofi as we can see here at R' Dovid Soloveitchik shlita home http://s1.kikar.net/th/data/auto/addonsmgr/ts/bu0cfiuo__w988h658q80.jpg Btw still a standard nusach ashkenazi siddur

Comment: IF you double or triple every word of krias shema then you'll have a brisker siddur.

Answer (score 9):

I studied in Brisk in Yerushalyim and what I saw from my Rosh Yeshiva and his family was that they use regular ashkenazi siddurim but by heart they incorporate their own nuschaos and minhagim (ie. most often following the Gr"a, for example, ommitting  **נא**  in the blessing of rachem in bentching. Also **ברחמיו** in Bonei Yerushalayim is omitted. However, they don't follow every addition/subtraction of the Gr"a. For example, they do not add a חתימת הברכה for Modim Derabanan or add נחם in place of רחם in Shabbos Bentching.

In summation there is no officially sanctioned siddur that is used by Briskers, rather the Mesora they have is incorporated when reciting it.

Comment: do you remember if they say Kir'useih (and not Chir'seih) in kaddish ? 
and do they ommit veyithalal in kaddish ? both are based on the Gra (maaseh rav)

Comment: @Frank i absolutely don’t remember